# How to Link Fields to Workflows?

Tags: workflow

I'm trying to create a workflow so that it tracks open or closed issues based on the status of the issue.

So on my **Related Lists** i have
 -Open Issues
 -Closed Issues

I want those to work but I don't know how. Right now they are just taking up space on the page but I need them to be functional.

How do I do this?

ty :S

Comment: What you have tried so far and where did you get stuck? Please update your question with those details.

Comment: Also, what does that mean? Workflows can perform record updates in response to changes, but "tracking" is kind of a higher-level description of functionality.

Comment: Please go through [how to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to get resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like someone has tried and failed to implement a filtered related list solution along the lines of Doug Ayers' [Filter Related Lists Without Code](https://douglascayers.com/2015/11/18/salesforce-filter-related-lists-without-code/).

If that's the case, you should expect to see two extra lookups on your issue object, one for Open status and one for Closed status. You'd need to complete the solution by adding automation (Ayers uses Process Builder in his example) that reacts to changes in the status of the Issue by setting or clearing the filter related lists as appropriate - i.e., when the status becomes Open, the lookup field for Closed is cleared and that for Open is populated with the value of the "real", unfiltered related list.

When that's done correctly, and if my guess as to what issue you're actually facing is near the mark, you'll see your related lists populate - but only after the process runs against them, which may require changing their statuses.